# How do I get float values between 0 and 1 from the y value using a UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

[image]I have a UIButton that I drag up and down on the y axis using the UIPanGestureRecognizer class. I'm using this instead of a UISlider for the vertical functionality. 
I want to capture all of the float values between 0 and 1 as a drag the button up and down like a UISlider would that is limited from a minimum value of 0 to a maximum of 1.

My current code isn't capturing the correct values. How can I fix this:

```
- (void)wasDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x,recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    //range is 139 pixels

    //i tried dividing 1/139 to get the increment using pixels

    if(newCenter.y >= 126 && newCenter.y <= 265)
    {
        currentMainVolValue = currentMainVolValue - 0.00714285714286; 
        recognizer.view.center = newCenter;
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set the minimum and maximum values of UI slider manually, and then divide them to get a float based on the sensitivity you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `126` is the smallest y value and `265` is the max. You need to subtract the smallest y from the current translation and then divide the result by the range

```
CGFloat minY  = 126;
CGFloat range = 256 - minY;

return 1 - ((yTranslation - minY) / range);
```

This gives

```
yTranslation = 256 then value = 0
yTranslation = 126 then value = 1
yTranslation = 191 then value = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I relied on `locationOfTouch` (*not* `translationInView`) and different `state` of gesture to achieve something similar.

In my case, i had to move a subview using an anchored button inside this subview (button registered for UIPanGestureRecognizer). Once gesture finishes, my view snaps again to left wall of screen (y-axis movement).

```
- (void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // Need to make below calculation for other orientations. Until then this is not allowed.
    if (self.interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) return;
    static CGFloat initialCenterPointX = 0;

    const CGPoint deltaPoint = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - gestureRecognizer.view.superview.center.x, self.view.bounds.size.height/2 - gestureRecognizer.view.superview.center.y);

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        initialCenterPointX = self.view.center.x;
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];

        NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer.view = %@ location = %f, %f", gestureRecognizer.view, location.x, location.y);
        CGFloat proposedCenterPointX = self.view.frame.origin.x + location.x;
        CGFloat proposedCenterPointY = self.view.frame.origin.y + deltaPoint.y + location.y;

        CGPoint newCenterLocation = CGPointZero;

        newCenterLocation.x = MAX(proposedCenterPointX, self.view.bounds.size.width/2);
        newCenterLocation.y = MAX(proposedCenterPointY, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);

        self.view.center = newCenterLocation;
    }
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.view.center = CGPointMake(initialCenterPointX, self.view.center.y);
        }];
    }
}
```